# I am unable to use "GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);" in a class

Tags: java, android

This is my code inside a java class.
 "GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)" was workin fine when I was using it in a Activity But it's showing errors on java class files.

*The error is "incompatible types: MessageAdapter cannot be converted to Context"*

**How can I get the Context value in this java class**

```
 @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

            Messages c = mMessageList.get(i);

            final String from_user = c.getFrom();
            String message_type = c.getType();



            mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(from_user);
            mUserDatabase.keepSynced(true);
            mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    //   String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    String image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();



**GoogleSignInAccount current_user = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);**



                    fuser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    if (!from_user.equals(fuser.getUid())) {

//                      viewHolder.displayName.setText(name);


                        Picasso.with(viewHolder.profileImage.getContext()).load(image)
                                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(viewHolder.profileImage);

                    }
                }
```

and this is another override method inside this class

```
 @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {


            **GoogleSignInAccount fuser = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context);**
            String fuser_id = fuser.getId();
            if (mMessageList.get(position).getFrom().equals(fuser_id)){
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;

            }
        }
```

Comment: That can happen due to millions of reason. Please post the relevant code block.

Comment: Post your full logcat

Comment: @Fantômas The error is "incompatible types: MessageAdapter cannot be converted to Context"

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straight forward, it states "incompatible types: MessageAdapter cannot be converted to Context".

You pass this as param, which at the current scope refers to the adapter. The method requires a context to work. 
There are multiple solutions for this, the the most lazy one I think is to get the context from viewholder class, like 
holder.itemView.getContext(), this solves the syntax error, but does not solve the structural problem.

There are other appraches like not handling such logic inside adapter, delegating the action would be a more elegant approach.

Also, learn about scopes in java, to understand the this reference.

Comment: did you ever heard of the tragedy of darth... I mean interfaces, lambdas and anonym classes? You can create an interface, which will be passed to the adapter. It can be the mainactivity which implements the listener, or a simple anonym class.

Comment: can you solve the problem for the 2nd override method @barotia

Comment: Sry but I think that you should make the research for yourself, we showed you the wayy from now, please do some effort.

Comment: I have found a way to do this..
Thank you @barotia and please upvote my question

Comment: Well, in fact you are the one who should upwote the answer if I helped :P